# JButton to open new frame, that is in different class

Tags: java, netbeans, linked-list, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to open new frame from my SecondFrame button. The Frame i want is the QueueFrame. However i have put the actionevent but it seems that there is no action when i press the button. This is my Deneme4 class

```
    public class Deneme4 extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    SecondFrame frame = new SecondFrame();

}}
```

when i do run this my first frame comes up which is the SecondFrame with no problem but in SecondFrame i have b3 and b4 i want each to open different class, for now i tried to open my QueueFrame with b4 but its not doing anything

Second Frame:

```
public class SecondFrame extends JFrame {

private JButton b3;
private JButton b4;

public SecondFrame() {

    JFrame secondframe = new JFrame();
    b3 = new JButton("Queue");
    b4 = new JButton("Stack");

    b3.setBounds(150, 100, 180, 100);
    b4.setBounds(150, 300, 180, 100);

    secondframe.add(b3);
    secondframe.add(b4);

    secondframe.setLayout(null);
    secondframe.setSize(500, 750);
    secondframe.setVisible(true);
    secondframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void b4ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws FileNotFoundException{

    QueueFrame queues = new QueueFrame();
    queues.setVisible(true);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));
    Queue queue = new Queue();
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        queue.setMessageOutput((Queue.MessageOutput) queues);
        queue.enqueue(s.nextInt());
    }
    s.close();
    queue.queueSize();
    queue.getHead();
}}
```

Comment: First, you need to have a read of [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write ActionListeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). You need to take the time learn how the API works, read through the tutorials and make an effort to hand code your UIs and not relying on the form editors, which hide much of the functionality you would otherwise need

Comment: I'd also recommend having a read of [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How MadProgrammer said... Read, and learn how to write: ActionListener's, cause you can't depends of form editors, is a bad practice.

Well, the only thing that you need to do is write a correct ActionListener, first the name of your class, and after, the name of your method.

```
yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
SecondFrame Sf = new SecondFrame();
Sf.frame();}});
```

Comment: Sure, no problem.